# Is there a command to change the STEM rotation angle?

Tags: hardware, dm-script

Does there exist a microscope control command in the DM scripting language to change the STEM rotation angle? That is, the direction the beam is moving across the sample. I would like to rotate 90 degrees between captures.

Comment: I am assuming your microcope uses Gatan's scanning hardware (Digiscan) ? Then see my answer below. Other scan generators (from the microscope) can not be accessed via DM scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The scan rotation is part of the scan-parameter set.**
>
> You can not
> change it during a running acquisition. Instead, you restart the acquisition with a new parameter set.
>
> ( If you use the UI, then the rotation function does this for you. The scan restarts automatically. )

For scripting, you specify the rotation as a parameter either when starting an acquisition with `DSAcquireData`:

```
number dataType = 4   // 4 byte data
number width    = 128 // pixel
number height   = 128 // pixel
image img := IntegerImage( "Img", dataType, 0, width, height )        // Image has to be of type unsigned-integer
 

number signalIndex = 0
number rotation = 0   // degree
number pixelTime= 2   // microseconds
number lineSync = 1   // activated

DSAcquireData( img, signalIndex, pixelTime, rotation, lineSync )
ShowImage( img )
```

Or when creating a parameter set which you then use with `DSStartAcquisition`:

```
number paramID
number width    = 512 // pixel
number height   = 512 // pixel
number rotation = 0   // degree
number pixelTime= 2   // microseconds
number lSynch   = 1   // activated

number continuous  = 0 // 0 = single frame, 1 = continuous
number synchronous = 1 // 0 = return immediately, 1 = return when finished

paramID = DSCreateParameters( width, height, rotation, pixelTime, lSynch )

number signalIndex, dataType, selected, imageID
signalIndex = 0
dataType    = 2 // 2 byte data
selected    = 1 // acquire this signal
imageID     = 0 // create new image
DSSetParametersSignal( paramID, signalIndex, dataType, selected, imageID )
DSStartAcquisition( paramID, continuous, synchronous )
DSDeleteParameters( paramID ) // remove parameters from memory
```

Both examples above have been directly copied form the F1 help documentation on Digiscan:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realised that the F1 help was so comprehensive! So as far as I understand, there is no way to change rotation during a digiscan acquisition - instead I must start an acquisition, stop, rotate, restart?

Comment: @TomNorway Correct. This is not a limitation of the scripting interface, but a limitation of the scan engine (hardware). ("Rotate" is not an action, but a parameter of the acquisition, just like the FOV or the sampling. All three together compute the actual beam positions/movement.)